# Ecto preload if not nil

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Phoenix n00b here.

I need to preload associations if the model exists. I wrote:

```
model = Repo.get(Model, id)
|> Repo.preload([:asso1, :asso2, :asso3])
```

But if model is not found, it fails because `Repo.preload` cannot stand receiving nil as a first argument:

> protocol Ecto.Queryable not implemented for nil, the given module does not exist. This protocol is implemented for: Ecto.Query, Atom, Ecto.SubQuery, Tuple, BitString

What would be the phoenix's way to achieve this?

I find a

```
model = if model = Repo.get(Model, id) do
  Repo.preload(model, [:asso1, :asso2, :asso3])
end
```

ugly.

Thanks

Comment: Your initial solution should work just fine. If you look at the [`Ecto.Repo.Preload/3` docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:preload/3) you can see that it takes `nil` as an argument. Are you sure that you passed in an existing `Model`? Your error seems to suggest that you called `Repo.get` like so... `Repo.get(nil, id)`. (> the given module does not exist)

Comment: You got it right, I don't know how I got confused but `MyApp.Repo.get(Vae.User, -1) |> MyApp.Repo.preload(:association)` works :)

Comment: Glad you got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens

```
model = Repo.get(Model, id)
|> Repo.preload([:asso1, :asso2, :asso3])
```

works even if `model` is `nil`. I must have made a mistake regarding the import of the `Model` module.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this: replacing Model and assoc with the corresponding associations, and it works.

```
model = Repo.get(Model, id)
|> Repo.preload([:asso1, :asso2, :asso3])
```

What I suggest it for you to try `preload/3` in `Query`:

```
model = Repo.one(from m in Model, where: [id: ^id], preload: [:assoc1, :assoc2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would:

```
case Repo.get(Model, id) do
  nil -> {:error, :not_found}
  model -> {:ok, model |> Repo.preload([:asso1, :asso2, :asso3])}
end
```

and stick that behind some function to be used by other parts of the application. That said, I think it's more a matter of a consistent style in your project/team than anything.

Comment: Ok thanks for your solution. I shall do something similar if nothing else is available. Ain't there any `safe_preload` method, that would do nothing on nil? Another `case` here is another level of indentation...

Comment: You could make `safe_preload` yourself... https://gist.github.com/JohnnyCrazy/4bd97f18035c87cf5faa62159f031b3b